# Show Y-Value of clicked slice/bar in MPAndroidChart piechart/barchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the MPAndroidChart library to display some graphs in my app (pie chart and bar chart). 
I don't want any textual description for the bars and slices, unless the user clicks on a slice/bar. Then only the description for this exact slice/bar should be displayed.

Right now I got some kind of workaround, which displays/undisplays all Y-values as soon as the user clicks on a slice/bar:

```
sessionsPieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {

                sessionsPieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
                pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {

                sessionsPieChart.setUsePercentValues(false);
                pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(0);
            }
        });
```

How can I only display the Y-Value of the clicked slice/bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all create MyMarkerView.java class in your project as:

```
public class MyMarkerView extends MarkerView {

private TextView tvContent;

public MyMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
    super(context, layoutResource);
    // this markerview only displays a textview
    tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
}

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)

@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight)
{
    // here you can change whatever you want to show in following line as x/y or both
    tvContent.setText("x: " + e.getX() + " , y: " + e.getY()); // set the entry-value as the display text
}

}
```

After that create following layout file custom_marker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

After that where you are creating chart add following code:

```
   MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(this, R.layout.custom_marker);
   combinedChart.setMarker(mv);
```